# Programmatically create nativescript-bottom element

Tags: nativescript

I would like to be able to set the selectedIndex of the nativescript-bottombar component. According to the documentation found [here](https://github.com/rhanb/nativescript-bottombar/blob/master/API.md),
I can do so by setting it programmatically on the bottombar. However, I'm having trouble understanding how I can do that.

On the xml file I initialize the component with

`<btn:BottomBar class="bottom-tab-bar" tabSelected="tabSelected" titleState="1" items="{{items}}" inactiveColor="#9B9B9B" accentColor="#4955F6"></btn:BottomBar>`

And in the onPageLoaded event I bind `page.bindingContext` to my model which has the items for the bottombar.

```
export class AudibleModel extends Observable {

    private _counter: number;
    private _message: string;    
    private _bottomBar: BottomBar;
    private _articles: ObservableArray<Article>; 

    public items: Array<BottomBarItem> = [
        new BottomBarItem(0, "Archive", "ic_archive_black", "#D8D8D8"),
        new BottomBarItem(1, "My List", "ic_list_black", "#D8D8D8"),
        new BottomBarItem(2, "Account", "ic_account_circle_black", "#D8D8D8")
    ];

    constructor() {
        super();
        this._bottomBar.items = this.items;

        this._articles =

            new ObservableArray([]);


    }

    get articles(): ObservableArray<Article> {      
        return this._articles;
    }
}
```

I'm not sure how I can link the view and the view model together so that I can create a component here. How can I create/modify the component programmatically so that I can set its `selectedIndex` property?

Answer (score 1):

Not fully an answer, but a possible solution seems to be to add this to the code behind:

```
export function tabLoaded(args) {
    let _bar = args.object as BottomBar;
    _bar.selectItem(1);
}
```

and on the xml element itself:

```
<btn:BottomBar class="bottom-tab-bar" loaded="tabLoaded" titleState="1" items="{{items}}" inactiveColor="#9B9B9B" accentColor="#4955F6"></btn:BottomBar>
```